# I don't want to print # sign in url

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, anchor

```
<a href="#" onClick="load_page()">intro</a>
```

I don't want to print # sign on URL, I wanted it to look like below :

```
www.mydomain.com/
```

But it looked like this

```
www.mydomain.com/#
```

Anyway to do this?

Comment: you can use `<span>` instead,  or to prevent the default action of the `a onclick` with `preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the URL to:

```
<a href="/" onClick="load_page(); return false;">intro</a>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

One popular way is to assign `href="javascript:void(0)"`
Another one is to prevent anchor default action via `return false` in click handler as **jacouh** answered. I would prefer the second way as more clean.

Comment: I prefer Jacouh method! thank you for explaining what "return false;" do!